# urlopen debug doesn't show header values

Tags: http, python-3.x, http-headers

In python3 ,I was trying to see the header values sent in the request

```
>>from urllib.request import  urlopen
>> url1='http://diveintopython3.org/examples/feed.xml'
>>from http.client import HTTPConnection as httpcon
>>httpcon.debuglevel = 1
>>resp1 = urlopen(url1)
```

this produced

```
send: b'GET /examples/feed.xml HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: diveintopython3.org\r\nUser-Agent: Python-urllib/3.3\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Cache-Control header: Pragma header: Content-Type header: Expires header: Server header: X-AspNet-Version header: X-Powered-By header: Date header: Content-Length header: Age header: Connection
```

whereas  curl gives me the header values

```
$curl -I http://diveintopython3.org/examples/feed.xml
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 783
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: ATS/3.2.4
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 31 May 2013 02:48:12 GMT
Age: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

what should I do to get the header values listed (as debug info) in python3 ?

Answer (score 0):

The object returned by `urllib.request.urlopen` being an `http.client.HTTPResponse` object, you can use all of the methods it defines. There is one called `getheaders` which does what you want:

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> url1 = 'http://diveintopython3.org/examples/feed.xml'
>>> r = urlopen(url1)
>>> r.getheaders()
[('Cache-Control', 'no-cache'), ('Pragma', 'no-cache'), ('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8'), ('Expires', '-1'), ('Server', 'ATS/3.2.4'), ('X-AspNet-Version', '4.0.30319'), ('X-Powered-By', 'ASP.NET'), ('Date', 'Fri, 31 May 2013 11:43:46 GMT'), ('Content-Length', '783'), ('Age', '0'), ('Connection', 'close')]
```

See the `http.client` documentation for more infos.